# How to append data at a particular line in a file using sed , where data is from another file

Tags: sed

Suppose I have a config file with some data , example file1.config , whose contents are:

```
flag_data_to_be_appended=xyz
```

and I have another file which is a shell script, example file2.sh , whose contents are:

```
./file.config
flag=abc
echo $flag
```

Now I need to append the information from file1 to file2 at flag , i.e output for flag has to look like :

```
flag=abc xyz
```

How can I do this with the help of "sed" command ?

Comment: The desired result is not valid shell script. If this is just a configuration file, that's moot, of course; but if you evaluate that file in the shell, it will assign `flag=abc` temporarily for the duration of its attempt to run `xyz` as a command. If you want to assign the whole string to `flag` you will need to escape spaces, or quote the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have `sed` write its own script?

```
sed -e "$(sed -e 's|^\(.*\)_data_to_be_appended=\(.*\)|/^\1=.*/ s//\& \2/|' cfg)" script
```

Inner command reads the config file and emits `/^flag=.*/ s//& xyz/`
which is then applied to the script file.

Output:

```
./file.config
flag=abc xyz
echo $flag
```

The two escaped parenthesis pairs capture key and value as `\1` and `\2`.
In `s//& \2/` the `//` is the null regex which matches the last
regex used (in `/^…/`) and replaces the entire match (`&`) followed
by the captured value.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^flag=/s#.*#sed "s/.*=/& /" file1#e' file2
```

Match the line starting `flag=` in file2 and replace its contents with the singleton lines contents after the `=` sign by way of a second sed invocation being applied in the RHS of a substitution.